# Wine Libasound2 File Conflict in 12.04 Wine 1.5/1.4 64bit

Tags: wine

When attempting to install Wine/PlayOnLinux on 64bit 12.04, I come across this error when installing 'libasound:1386'.

```
(Reading database ... 153318 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking libasound2:i386 (from .../libasound2_1.0.25-1ubuntu10_i386.deb) ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/libasound2_1.0.25-1ubuntu10_i386.deb unpack):
'./usr/share/alsa/pcm/surround71.conf' is different from the same file on the system
```

Is there any way of fixing this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, I solved it by installing the following package.

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/precise/amd64/libasound2/1.0.25-1ubuntu10

regards